# PHP Exec Function

Tags: php, csv, xls

I am writing a PHP script that will run XLS to CSV conversion. I am using `exec()` but I am unable to get the program to run. I have looked through most of the comments regarding this topic to no avail.

```
<?php
    $pXCExe="C:Program Files (x86)\XLS to CSV\xls2csv.exe";
    $pXLSFileName="C:\TestExcell\vaca.xls";
    $pOutFileName="C:\TestExcell\vca.csv";
    $olines=0;
    $ecode=0;

    echo $R = exec($pXCExe.' "'. $pXLSFileName. '" "'. $pOutFileName .'"'.'"'/silent''"'.'"/fields=pipe'"', $olines, $ecode);

?>
```

Comment: I don't get errors but the file is never converted.

Comment: You leave out a lot of code. What is `$pXCExe` for example, and what about the other variables. Also, does the command work on the command line?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get errors? Also not in the logs?

Comment: I will check the logs. Actually I haven't gotten it to run on the cmd line. I will try that. $pXCExe is the path to the conversion program execute.

Comment: I have gotten it to run via cmd line - xls2csv.exe C:\TestExcell\mts.xlsx C:\TestExcell\ /OPEN=1 /SILENT /FIELDS=PIPE

Answer (score 0):

As the path to the program contains spaces, make sure you quote it in the **command**:

```
$pXCExe = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\XLS to CSV\xls2csv.exe"';
```

And backslashes within double quotes are treated as escape characters, so for `$pXLSFileName` and `$pOutFileName`, do not use double quotes:

```
$pXLSFileName = 'C:\TestExcell\vaca.xls';
$pOutFileName = 'C:\TestExcell\vca.csv';
```

or escape the backslashes if you want to keep the double quotes:

```
$pXLSFileName = "C:\\TestExcell\\vaca.xls";
$pOutFileName = "C:\\TestExcell\\vca.csv";
```